# How to do mapGetters in asyncData? Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

My goal is to pass a getter object inside asyncData, because I need to access the state to pass data to axios

Code example

```
export default {
   async asyncData() {
      let result = await $axios.$post('/api/test', { data: this.totalPrice })
   },
   computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["totalPrice"])
   }
}
```

As you can see I want to access getter object in `asyncData` However I got

[image]

Comment: maybe this could help https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#using-async-await

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/)...

> **Warning**: You **don't** have access to the component instance through `this` inside `asyncData` because it is called **before initiating** the component.

Instead, use the [`context`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) object provided

```js
async asyncData ({ store }) {
  const body = { data: store.getters.totalPrice }
  const { data } = await $axios.$post('/api/test', body)
  return data
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but why do all my vuex getters are empty whenever I refresh the page? btw Im using vuex-persisted to persist the data in localstorage just in case I refresh the page. Any clue? thanks man

Comment: Vuex-persisted is only available on the client side.  So when asyncData is run server side, it cannot access the client data, which is why it's empty.

Answer (score -2):

Methods should be placed into methods to have the vue context:

```
export default {
   methods : {
      async asyncData() {
         let result = await $axios.$post('/api/test', { data: this.totalPrice })
      }
   },
   computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["totalPrice"])
   }
}
```

If you want to do it onload use mounted (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

```
export default {
   async mounted() {
      let result = await $axios.$post('/api/test', { data: this.totalPrice })
   },
   computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["totalPrice"])
   }
}
```

Comment: The my comment stil makes sence as this is described on the page you provide:
`You don't have access to the component instance through this inside asyncData because it is called before initiating the component.` as the computed value is part of the component

Comment: I just meant that `asyncData` doesn't go in to `methods`

Comment: Ok your right, but still you can have a async method in your methods :)